# Http post request to send form data in image format

Tags: c#

Hi I have below code to send the data, but in return I get server error with error code 500, the file is
not getting sent through the request

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong

```
   FileStream rdr = new FileStream("C:/Users/AR485UY/Desktop/Test1.pdf", FileMode.Open)

   HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url" );

string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

req.Method = "POST"; 

req.ContentLength = rdr.Length;

req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" +boundary;

req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();

byte[] inData = new byte[rdr.Length];

int len = Convert.ToInt32(rdr.Length);

int bytesRead = rdr.Read(inData, 0, len);

reqStream.Write(inData, 0, len);

rdr.Close();

req.GetResponse();

reqStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

if it never work :
Most likely have to validate your server side api,script,logs,events,diagnostics trace,file size limits.

Also try another approach in c#:

```
try
{
    using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
   {
    string myFile = @"C:/Users/AR485UY/Desktop/Test1.pdf";
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    client.UploadFile(url, "POST", myFile);

    }
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
}
```

Comment: Hi, There is no issue with the API, I get a response in postman, I will try this out